# How to make julia kernel available when running jupyter notebook on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, putty

I am running my jupyter notebook on ubuntu on a VM but I don't know how to make the Julia kernel available in this case. Can someone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but why not simply install Julia (and the IJulia package) on the VM? Maybe you can clarify a bit more what you want to run where.

Comment: If you want to work on a Client but have calculations run on a different Server there is Jupyter Hub.

Comment: I have never worked with a VM before so I don't know how to install it on the VM? I use putty to start the notebook on the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Julia and the IJulia package on the VM.

Assuming you're running a generic Linux on the VM, the steps should be (roughly) like this:

1. Download Julia: `wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.2/julia-1.2.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
2. Unpack the tarball: `tar -xf julia-1.2.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
3. Execute Julia: `./julia-1.2.0/bin/julia`
4. Install IJulia: `] add IJulia`
5. Start the Jupyter notebook server (from within Julia): `using IJulia; notebook()`

In principle, IJulia should figure out which local `python` you are using and will use this existing one. In this case the Julia Kernel should be available even if you start the jupyter notebook server from outside of Julia. If it can't figure it out, open Julia and set `ENV["PYTHON"] = "/my/path/to/python"` followed by `] build IJulia`. If you don't know what `/my/path/to/python` is use `which python` to find out. For more, see [IJulia.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I did all the steps but when I enter `notebook()` I get this Output:   `[ Info: running setenv(`/usr/bin/jupyter notebook`,["IPPROOT=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/ipp", "CPATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/ipp/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.linux/mkl/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199... ` but jupyter doesn't open in the browser.

Comment: Try to open `http://localhost:8888/tree` in the browser manually. Does it work?

Comment: It asks me for the token but the token is not included in the output after running `notebook()`